# How to add a column to a multiindex dataframe with .loc?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one line of code that I wrote about half a year ago. When I execute it today, I'll get an error. I think I'll updated pandas in the meantime. It's best to shown it with an example.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([pd._testing.rands_array(2, 4),
                  pd._testing.rands_array(2, 4),
                  pd._testing.rands_array(2, 4),
                  pd._testing.rands_array(2, 4)],
                  columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("foo", 'a1'), ("foo", 'a2'),("bar", 'b1'), ("bar", 'b2')]))
print(df1)
# prints:
#   foo     bar    
#    a1  a2  b1  b2
# 0  wT  qX  Mj  LR
# 1  Jd  Bq  VB  5s
# 2  PZ  xJ  lb  5Z
# 3  tv  VB  mI  Rw

df1.loc[[0,1,2], "asdf"] = 5
```

As described, `df1.loc[[0,1,2], "asdf"] = 5` worked before. The only solution I have so far is `df1.loc[[1,2], ("asdf", "")] = 5`. However, is there a possibility to add level0 column `"asdf"` without specifying columns level1?

Expected outcome:

```
#   foo     bar     asdf
#    a1  a2  b1  b2     
# 0  1b  8U  Hx  mm  5.0
# 1  fA  N0  CW  Wh  5.0
# 2  4O  aX  nF  6i  5.0
# 3  cS  hK  rs  ur  NaN
```

Obtained error message:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: In pandas 1.2.1, `df1.loc[[0,1,2], "asdf"] = 5` works without issue to created the desired result. I'm voting to close this as Not Reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote this question my pandas version was 1.1.5, where this strange behaviour of my code occurs.
Updating to pandas 1.2.1 solved this issue. Thank you for your comment Trenton McKinney.